# Pipeline Accumulator VHDL

Tags: algorithm, vhdl

After dealing with a `Pipeline Multiplier` and a `Signed Adding Accumulator`, I was wondering if I could implement a `Pipeline Accumulator` in VHDL.

Since the `Accumulator` utilized the Core-Gen I don't know how to go about this...maybe use registers in place of the accumulator and then keep updating the registers? I'd appreciate any ideas and help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate the accumulator in Core-Gen, you can specify the desired latency.  The Xilinx tools will insert the appropriate number of registers and optimize the adder logic for you auto-magically.

See the Xilinx data-sheet for their Accumulator function for full usage details.

Answer (score 1):

A pipelined accumulator is fairly simple. For a 32-bit accumulator, break the 32-bits into chunks that fit in each pipeline stage -- I'll use 8-bits in each pipeline stage for this example. You will then need 4 stages to compute it. Each stage of 8-bits has an overflow bit, which is used as the carry-in to the 8-bits in the next stage.

Answer (score 1):

The MAC core wrapper in `coregen` will handle it all out-of-the-box. Simply plug in what you need to multiply/accumulate, tell it you want it signed, and then play with the pipeline depths. It's the classic speed/size trade-off.